# PHP. Как правильно вызвать метод родителя?

Tags: php, ооп, symfony, guzzle, extend

Возникла такая проблема. Я хочу переопеределить класс Guzzle на свой, чтобы встроить логирование в метод request. Проблема: я логирую результат запроса, поэтому хочу внутри делать что-то вроде -

```
$request = parent::request(...);
// код логирования
return $request
```

НО код после parent::request() попросту не работает.

Например:

```
$request = parent::request(...);
// чтобы я здесь не написал, оно игнорируется
```

В интернете в примерах пишут parent::method и после этого спокойно echo "..." делают, но я не могу ничего сделать после того как был вызван parent::request(). Даже если я его просто вызываю, то он будто делает неявный return и возвращать результат сразу. Весь код ДО исполняется без проблем, но мне нужен результат parent::request. Если я сделаю $this->request, то сами понимаете, что происходит :) Я вхожу в рекурсию.

Помогите, пожалуйста)

Comment: Вы уверены что исполнение доходит до этого места? Может быть проблемы с переопределением класса?

Comment: Доходит. Вызываю дебаггер до parent::request - вижу, вызываю после - не вижу. При этом результат реквеста пришёл, я его вижу и могу с ним работать

Comment: Я понял, проблема в том, что это Promise, который вызывается через wait и похоже это как-то аффектит последующие вызовы. Пока не особо понимаю как с этим бороться. Сижу гуглю :)

Comment: Я бы посмотрел на предмет Middleware , например. Может там что то можно добавить толкового. https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/handlers-and-middleware.html